# Variable scope in loops

Tags: javascript

I am a bit confused http://jsfiddle.net/

```
{
    for (var counter = 1; counter < 6; counter++) {

    }
}
console.log(counter);
```

If variables from loops are available in the scope the `for loop` is created, then why do I have access to the variable one level higher, since I created another scope by putting those brackets?

Comment: Javascript only knows object scope and function scope. There's no block scope.

Comment: Variables have function level scope, not block level...

Comment: Ah, now I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables created with the `var` keyword have *function scope* (or *global scope* if they're declared outside of a function).

ES6 introduces the `let` keyword for *block scoped* variables.

Answer (score 4):

Loops do not have their own scopes.

A loop is a block, and blocks do not have their own scopes; variables created with `var` can only have function or global scope.

As others have pointed out, in ES6, you will be able to use block-scoped variables with the `let` keyword.

Comment: I know, the scope is the same as the one in which they were created. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. If you do `for(var counter = 1...)`, `counter` will be available from that point forward in the function containing this loop (or globally, if it is not in a function).

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong, loops do not have scopes.